# JS Function works only on one (first one) element

Tags: javascript, events, click, handler

I am trying to accept JS plugin for all `links#modal_trigger` in my website, but it works only with the first one. What's wrong? I can't get to know.

My JS codes:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal:function(options){
            var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};
            var overlay=$("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options=$.extend(defaults,options);
            $(this).each(function(i){
                var o=options;
                $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
                    var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").bind('click', function() {close_modal(modal_id)});
                    $(o.closeButton).bind('click', function() {close_modal(modal_id)});
                    var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();
                    $("#lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);
                    $(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed","opacity":0,"z-index":11000,"left":50+"%","margin-left":-(modal_width/2)+"px","top":o.top+"px"});
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()
                })
            });
            function close_modal(modal_id){
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

And :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
        $(function(){
        $(".user_login").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Because you can only have one element with that id on the page (and so the code will only work with the first one it finds). You need to switch to classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that's not working is because you have multiple elements in your document with the same ID. You need to be using classes instead, and using class selectors.  When you have multiple elements with the same ID `myId`, `$('#myId')` will return only one element. So instead, give your elements a class `class="modal_trigger"` and use the selector `$('.modal_trigger')`.

Comment: BIG BIG thanks! I started to love this forum. As I see there I am going to improve my js skills!

Comment: I've tried to upvote, mate. Just can't becouse of low reputation, I am a newbie at this website.